# How to split string then compare it to fill id's in relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have 2 Tables:

- `Molecule` containing :

  -`id`

  -`MainName` (ex: caffeine)
- `JsonTextMining` containing :

  -`id`

  -`solrId` (ex: PMC54233)

  -`MoleculeName` (ex: caffeine | aspirin | sugar )

They are ManyToMany relation so there is a third table `jsonTextMiningMolecule` that have:

-`json_text_mining_id`

-`molecule_id`

I want to find a postgresql command that can split the `moleculeName` string and then compare with `mainName` to attribute id's in `jsonTextMiningMolecule`

For the moment i got something like this :

edit:

```
update json_text_mining_molecule SET molecule_id = molecule.id
FROM molecule, json_text_mining
WHERE split_part(json_text_mining.molecule_name, ' | ', 2 ) = molecule.main_name
```

The result of this command is update 0 (perhap's because i have non null constraint on `json_text_mining_id`) and split_part don't work as he need to choose one part of the string

Comment: please update OP with data samples and wanter result samples

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into `split_part` command. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

You can find many other string operations in there!

EDIT:

 Try `regexp_split_to_array` with `IN` clause

Comment: Thanks for the documentation page but unfortunately `split_part` don't suit as i need all names in the string and not only one

Comment: @Gy0m check the edit. It would split the string to array. Hope it works!